# Unity3D and Photon Networking RPG

Tags: unity, c#, rpg, photon

Good time of the day.
My question might sound stupid, due to the knowledge you might have, but here it is.

I've purchased Diablo 3 a long time ago and been enjoying it since then. Since many of my friend are playing other Blizzard titles, i tried to convince them to purchase Diablo and to play all together. However, they don't want to invest money in the game they don't understand (yet).

So i've decided to write a game, which will be similar to the Diablo in the way of interaction and gameplay, but will (obviously) have some unique points in it (since i'm not only doing this for them, but also to educate myself in the game development area). Other this is, i've decided to take Masters in the Game Development (later this march, just got my bachelors in computer security) and wanted to have some basic knowledge about game development.

I used to make "RPG" games before, tho only browser style ones using LAMP stack, and have some basic knowledge on storing/retrieving data to/from server.

In order to implement multiplayer part of the game, i've decided to use free package PUN (Photon Unity Networking). Had no problem with creating my first room and spawning a player prefab for every new connection (tho they all move no matter on which client action is performed).

**Now to the question(s):**

1. By using PUN, i'm able to create new room for players (limited to 5), is it possible to set room names BEFORE they are actually initialized by the player? (set of rooms might be stored on MySQL server and retrieved by the API call)
2. Is it possible to save progression of the player on the server, and later pass it back to the spawned player (by PUN). This is my main concern, since i've no actual access to the data processed by the server. (Solution is to create another connection to the "storage" server, and keep both of them "online"?)
3. Does PUN allows you to select which scene should be loaded upon first player entering the room, if so, a bit of pseudo code might be helpful.
4. What will happen to the player, if there is no spots left to join the server (this is just theoretical question, since i'm not going to publish this game, and amount of friends playing games is less than 20)
5. How would one deal with the item equipped, which is received during the gameplay? (This one links to the second question) What i'm talking about is, is it possible to restore player object with the set of data received form the server (if possible, ofcourse)

I know, the first suggestion will be to go and to read documentation (i'm in the process of reading it, don't worry). But i've decided to write here, since there are many skilled people out there in this area, who can give me basic understanding on how this whole PUN system works.

I would like to thank you for all of the responses, which you are about to post (or maybe not), and again, have a great day.

Comment: Welcome to Game Development! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! Also, this is a huge undertaking for a single developer (with limited experience), so it may be wise to convince your friends by other means to play a game with you.

Comment: This is really compact. Anyway, PUN is not a great way to do controlled environments because it's P2P if you don't want to pay for a server. Here's a recent question on this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/server-logic-on-client-side/135060#135060